# Promise Chain in Nodejs/Q

Tags: node.js, promise, q, chaining

I have a collection where an Item can be anothers parent and at the same time be another's child(it has a ItemCode and a ParentCode which is ItemCode of its parent).it may have multiple childs. I want to find all childrens of `firstItemCode`.at first I find every Item with ParentCode equal to first ItemCode then I do it again for every child found.like so:

```
var totals = [];
collection.find({'parentCode': firstItemCode.toString()}).then(function(d) {
        // console.log(d);
        d.forEach(function(u){
            totals.push({'itemCode': u['itemCode'], 'name':u['name'], 'name': u['price']});
            collection.find({'parentCode': u['itemCode'].toString()}).then(function(d1){
                d1.forEach(function(u1){
                    totals.push({'itemCode': u1['itemCode'], 'name':u1['name'], 'name': u1['price']});
                    collection.find({'parentCode': u1['itemCode'].toString()}).then(function(d2){
                        d2.forEach(function(u2){
                            totals.push({'itemCode': u2['itemCode'], 'name':u2['name'], 'name': u2['price']});
                            collection.find({'parentCode': u2['itemCode'].toString()}).then(function(d3){
                                console.log(totals);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });

});
```

I want to do this until there is no more items in collection with a parent code equal to last item's code

I tried [this](https://daveceddia.com/waiting-for-promises-in-a-loop/) tutorial but I got confused... I dont know how to fit `forEach` in chaining.
Can anyone help me do this in a loop so I dont have to copy this 100 times?

Comment: You [don't fit `forEach` in chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572) at all, because it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Have you heard of recursion?

Comment: @Bergi I dont know how to return from every child

Comment: @Bergi `for...of` only returns the first one

Comment: You are not supposed to `return` from the middle of the loop. You are supposed to return a (promise for an) array.